# Why doesn't my BeautifulSoup code return the contents of these UL elements?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to find the lowest train ticket price in Eurostar. For some reason, the code does not retrieve information from the "ul" tables when theoretically it should.

The code is the following:

```
input_parser = InputParser()
input_parser.inputDestinations("London","Paris")
input_parser.adults=2
input_parser.inputDates("2021-10-08","2021-10-10")

URL = input_parser.createURL()
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

results = soup.find_all("ul", {"class": "train-table"})
```

The class input parser basically returns the URL based on the particular data:

```
class InputParser():

    def __init__(self):
        self.mapOfDestinations = {"London": "7015400", "Paris": "8727100", "Brussels": "8814001"}
        self.destinations = []
        self.adults = 0
        self.departureDate = ""
        self.arrivalDate = ""

    def inputDestinations(self, departureDestination, arrivalDestination):
        self.destinations.append(self.mapOfDestinations[departureDestination])
        self.destinations.append(self.mapOfDestinations[arrivalDestination])

    def inputDates(self, departureDate, arrivalDate):
        self.departureDate = departureDate
        self.arrivalDate = arrivalDate

    def inputAdults(self, numberOfAdults):
        self.adults = numberOfAdults

    def createURL(self):
        default_URL = "https://booking.eurostar.com/uk-en/train-search?origin={0}&destination={1}&adult={2}&outbound-date={3}&inbound-date={4}". \
            format(self.destinations[0], self.destinations[1], self.adults, self.departureDate, self.arrivalDate)
        return default_URL
```

My code should return the "ul" table linked to the "train-table", but it returns None. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

If you want to look at the source code the code gives the following URL: https://booking.eurostar.com/uk-en/train-search?origin=7015400&destination=8727100&adult=1&outbound-date=2021-10-08&inbound-date=2021-10-10

Comment: it seems this page uses JavaScript to add elements but `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` can't run JavaScript. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript. Or you can check in DevTools in Firefox/Chrome if JavaScript read data from other URL (from some API) and use this URL to get data without scraping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you see is loaded from external URL so BeautifulSoup doesn't see it. But you can use the `requests` module to simulate this query:

```py
import json
import requests

origin = "7015400"
destination = "8727100"

api_url = f"https://api.prod.eurostar.com/bpa/train-search/uk-en/{origin}/{destination}"
params = {
    "outbound-date": "2021-10-08",
    "inbound-date": "2021-10-10",
    "adult": "1",
    "booking-type": "standard",
}

headers = {"X-apikey": "0aa3d4b7e805493c8e310cfb871c4344"}

data = requests.get(api_url, params=params, headers=headers).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for j in data["outbound"]["journey"]:
    for c in j["class"]:
        if "price" in c:
            print(
                "{:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10}".format(
                    j["departureTime"],
                    j["arrivalTime"],
                    c["remaining"],
                    c["price"]["adult"],
                )
            )
```

Prints:

```
07:01      10:17      150        134.5     
07:01      10:17      20         149.5     
07:01      10:17      47         245       
08:01      11:17      70         134.5     
08:01      11:17      2          179.5     
08:01      11:17      30         245       
10:24      13:47      27         134.5     
10:24      13:47      10         179.5     
10:24      13:47      31         245       
12:24      15:47      70         134.5     
12:24      15:47      50         219.5     
12:24      15:47      13         245       
16:31      19:47      7          134.5     
16:31      19:47      41         219.5     
16:31      19:47      31         245       
19:01      22:17      45         134.5     
19:01      22:17      8          149.5     
19:01      22:17      42         245       
20:01      23:17      35         74.5      
20:01      23:17      19         119.5     
20:01      23:17      51         245
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This has been very useful. I also wanted to automate the code so that you could obtain any data from any date/destinations that you want. Is there anyway to obtain the x-apikey automatically?